# Inject @Controller into another spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

In a spring mvc project, I want to inject a @Controller into a different bean, something like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  ..
}

@Component
public class SomeSpringBean {
  @Resource
  private MyController myController;

  ..
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, although the @Controller annotation is a specialization of @Component, just as e.g. @Service (which does work):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com..Mycontroller] is defined
```

I've also tried to get the bean from the ApplicationContext directly.

I'd like to avoid any discussions about why I want to inject controllers and that I should rather create an additional level of abstraction and inject it instead :)

Comment: The message means that there is no `MyController` in the Spring context where SomeSpringBean is defined(either controller is in Dispatcher Servlet Context - (but that would inevitable lead to discussions :-)) or it's not autoscanned at all). P.S. when you autowire by type i.e. you know that its type is MyController you should use `@Autowired` or `@Inject` instead, `@Resource` is used to wire beans by name -   it's not a good practice to use the "fall-back" behaviour of `@Resource` specific only to Spring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your `SomeSpringBean` class is component scanned by the root context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

I'm going to assume that your `@Controller` annotated classes are scanned by the servlet context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

In this case, the root context does not have access to the beans in the servlet context. Only the inverse is true.

You will need to put the `SomeSpringBean` class in some other package that will have to be scanned by the servlet context.

---

<sub>If my assumptions are wrong, please add your context configurations.</sub>

---

This is not a good idea. `@Controller` beans are meant to be managed by the `DispatcherServlet`'s `HandlerMapping` stack. I can't think of anything you would want to get from a `@Controller` bean.

Comment: Bingo! It's the 2 application contexts again. Thanks. As for why I wanted to do it - The controllers expose REST services, which are consumed by external clients. Apart from this, I wanted to include the results of the same services in a different model. I'll have to do it a different way.